# CodeIgniter - unable to query database

Tags: codeigniter, expressionengine

I have written a function, and it's working except one part:

```
//Find current upload total value   
$this->EE->db->select('upload_total');
$upload_total = $this->EE->db->get_where('exp_competition_purchase_upload_total', array('member_id' => $member_id));
return $upload_total->result();

// If upload total is more than 0       
if($upload_total > 0) {
    $new_total = $upload_total + $my_data['upload_total'];  
    $my_data['upload_total'] = $new_total;
}
```

Can anyone tell me if they can see any issue with this particular part of the code?

Here is the full function. It runs in an extension. The extension is working, it just appears to be the above code that isnt.

I am basically just trying to find the value in the db, then if the value is more than one, add the value to another.

```
function cartthrob_on_authorize()
{
    foreach ($this->EE->cartthrob->cart->items() as $item) { 

        // Create array to store member id and purchased upload slots
        $my_data = array(
            'member_id' => $this->EE->session->userdata('member_id'),
            'upload_total' => $item->item_options('fees'),
        );

        // Store member id in variable
        $member_id = $my_data['member_id'];  

        // Query table to check if there is record with member id exists
        $query = $this->EE->db->get_where('exp_competition_purchase_upload_total', array('member_id' => $member_id)); 

        // If query returns more than 0 update record 
        if($query->num_rows() > 0) {

            //Find current upload total value   
            $this->EE->db->select('upload_total');
            $upload_total = $this->EE->db->get_where('exp_competition_purchase_upload_total', array('member_id' => $member_id));

            // If upload total is more than 0       
            if($upload_total > 0) {

                $new_total = $upload_total + $my_data['upload_total'];  

                $my_data['upload_total'] = $new_total;

            }   

            return $upload_total->result();

            $this->EE->db->where('member_id', $member_id);
            $this->EE->db->update('exp_competition_purchase_upload_total', $my_data);

        // If query returns 0 insert new record         
        } else {

            $this->EE->db->insert('exp_competition_purchase_upload_total', $my_data);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah u cannot run code after u have returned... 'return $upload_total->result();' should be done after ur conditional statement

Comment: are you sure you are having result from db when you call `$this->EE->db` ?

Comment: micb : if I add it after I have the error: Object of class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to int.

Comment: rcpayan : Yes. This code is to work inside Expression Engine, which is run off codeigniter.

Comment: @ccdavies Where do you want `if($upload_total > 0) { //some code; }` to be executed??? in model or in controller???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Find current upload total value   
$this->EE->db->select('upload_total');
$upload_total = $this->EE->db->get_where('exp_competition_purchase_upload_total', array('member_id' => $member_id))->result_array();
$upload_total = $upload_total[0];
//If upload total is more than 0
$upload_total_col = $upload_total['upload_total']>0 ? $upload_total['upload_total']:0;
$my_data['upload_total'] += $upload_total_col;
```

From what I understand you, just want to increment upload_total.

**Note**: Don't use `return $upload_total->result();` in between your function without putting a condition.

Comment: For if($upload_total->num_rows() > 0) { I am not looking to count rows. I want to see if the value in the upload_total column is greater than 1. I have added the full code in my post with more explanation just above.

Comment: @ccdavies `$upload_total->num_rows() > 0` -> This will check if the query has returned some value from db. If you want to check the value of upload_total column check my edit...

Comment: Thank you. I just tried it, and it returns :  Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object

Comment: So r U using [philsturgeon codeigniter-restserver](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver) to access codeigniter functions???

Comment: No. I am running it through Expression Engine.

Comment: Oops sry, I had used `$upload_total = $upload_total->result_array();` before `$upload_total->num_rows() > 0`. Thats why you got that error... I've edited my code now...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30003/discussion-between-ccdavies-and-elavarasan-lee)

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution

```
$this->EE->db->select('upload_total');
$upload_total = $this->EE->db->get_where('exp_competition_purchase_upload_total',     array('member_id' => $member_id));

// If upload total is more than 0       
if($upload_total->num_rows() > 0) {
    $result = $upload_total->row_array();
    $new_total = $result['upload_total'] + $my_data['upload_total'];  
    $my_data['upload_total'] = $new_total;
}
return $my_data;
```

try that. it was becuase u was trying to use the DB returned object as an int.

Comment: p.s. i didn't test it but it should point u along the right path :)

Comment: `$result + $my_data['upload_total'];` -> You are trying to add an array with some integer value... He's also doing the same mistake just that in his case its object...

Comment: ah well spotted lol... not something i would of missed normally :P

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think its what I need. I need to get the value from the database, then check to see if that value is more than 0 (not columns but the value) and then add the new value to the old if it is.

Answer (score 0):

result of query is not an integer, it is an object

try like this;

```
//Find current upload total value   
$this->EE->db->select('upload_total');
$upload_total = $this->EE->db->get_where('exp_competition_purchase_upload_total', array('member_id' => $member_id));

$result = $upload_total->result();

// If upload total is more than 0       
if($upload_total->num_rows() > 0) {
    $my_data['upload_total'] += $result->upload_total;
}

return $my_data;
```

btw, I'm not sure what you want to do, so i just corrected it!